# How to not duplicate records in a single BigQuery table, and get totals per month, from a single table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got one huge table (as it goes in BigQuery) with what is essentially an eventlog. I'm trying to get a count of "new" records (where the event did not occur in the previous month).

The rows looks something like:

```
timestamp                    event_name        number   grouping_name
Sep. 08, 2019, 04:35 a.m.    imaginary name    12345    imaginary group
Sep. 08, 2019, 04:35 a.m.    imaginary name    98765    imaginary group
Oct. 14, 2019, 08:35 p.m.    imaginary name    12345    imaginary group
Nov. 16, 2019, 12:30 p.m.    imaginary name    12345    imaginary group
Nov. 16, 2019, 12:31 p.m.    imaginary name2   54321    imaginary group
```

I'm trying to get the following from it:

```
month   count
sep     2
oct     0
nov     1
```

So 12345 is counted in Sept, but not again.

I've tried a variety of approaches, from with's to using the window functions and I cannot seem to wire something together that works.

My latest failed attempt was:

```
WITH eventlogs AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM mytable
  WHERE grouping = 'mygroup'
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT number)
FROM (
  SELECT
    number, timestamp,
    FIRST_VALUE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2019-04-01')) OVER (PARTITION BY anothergroup ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  FROM eventlog
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2019-04-30'))
```

The query isn't returning an error, but the result certainly does not look correct. With a smaller data set it seemed fine :-(

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a day by day count of new items you can do this:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.wikipedia.pageviews_2019`
  WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN "2019-09-01" AND "2019-09-10"
  AND wiki='es'
  AND title LIKE 'Abe%'
  AND views>10
)

SELECT first_day, COUNT(*) c, STRING_AGG(title LIMIT 10) new_items
FROM (
  SELECT title, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(MIN(datehour), DAY) first_day
  FROM data
  GROUP BY title
)
GROUP BY first_day
ORDER BY first_day
```

[image]

Change `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC()` from `DAY` to `MONTH` for monthly results.

Comment: Thanks Felipe! That works perfectly! Any idea how I would add the complete distinct total column to this query? Would be nice to have both those in one result for easier eyeballing :-D

Comment: @Ruz . . . You accepted this answer.  However, I'm lost on how this gets "new records (where the event did not occur in the previous month)."

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have you got an alternative suggestion? On face value the result seems fine, but I will do more testing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Mmm, I get a 99.8% dropoff now in the data, which is almost certainly incorrect. Wargh :-(

Comment: 99% drop-off? How do you mean? Note the query above has a `LIMIT 10` to show the new elements

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Apologies :facepalm: It would help if I actually ensure there is something to compare to. Bit or burnout I guess. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.